# How to put legend inside a ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot and I have customized its legend; I want to place the legend top horizontal. How to do that?

I have tried placing it as follows, but it is not working.

```
style1 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}]};
style2 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{8, 20}]};
style3 = PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{4, 18, 40}]};
style4 = PlotStyle -> {"LineColor" -> None};

legend = LineLegend[
   Directive[#2] & @@@ {style1, style2, style3, style4}, {Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(1\)]\),", 40]], 
    Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(2\)]\),", 40]], 
    Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(β\), \(2\)]\),", 40]], 
    Text[Style["FEM", 40]]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {None, None, None, {"○", 40}}];

fig = ListLogLinearPlot[
   Select[RandomReal[{0, π}, {5000, 2}], 
    IntervalMemberQ[Interval[Sort[eqns[First@#]]], Last@#] &], 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, Frame -> True];
fig = Legended[fig, Placed[legend, Above]];
fig = Style[fig, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> 1000}]
```

Comment: won't something like `PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {.5, .9}]` inside the `ListLogLinearPlot` work?

Comment: @Rupesh Only texts are coming but lines are not coming, instead of lines black dots are appearing

Comment: Please provide the definitions for `eqns` so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: "but this is not working" - please be specific as to what is not working, or include a picture of the output. Unless there is an obvious flaw in the output, we cannot guess what you would consider a good result, and you do not provide full definitions to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

As Rupesh suggested

```
{style1, style2, style3} =
  {Black, Thickness[0.004], AbsoluteDashing[#]} & /@
   {{2, 7}, {8, 20}, {4, 18, 40}};
style4 = {Black};

legend = LineLegend[
   Directive @@@ {style1, style2, style3, style4},
   Text[Style[#, 40]] & /@
    {Subscript[β, 1], Subscript[β, 2], Subscript[β, 2], "FEM"},
   LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1},
   LegendMarkers -> {None, None, None, {"○", 40}}];

SeedRandom[2]

fig =
 ListLogLinearPlot[
  Sort /@ RandomReal[{0, π}, {4, 5, 2}],
  PlotStyle -> Directive @@@ {style1, style2, style3, style4},
  PlotMarkers -> {None, None, None, {"○", 40}},
  Joined -> {True, True, True, False},
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 1000,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {.5, .95}]]
```

[image]